# Python user defined exception handling

Tags: python-2.7, exception, error-handling

i need a little bit of help understanding a problem that i have with user defined exceptions in python 2.7.11.

I have two files **main.py** and **myErrors.py** .in **main** i post data and receive a response and and in **myErrors** i handle the errors.

What i'm trying to do is execute the version error in the try:except statement, but it doesn't get executed even thought it should be. what i'm doing is that i pass the response to myErrors and update that data to a dictionary in the errors file.-

my question was badly phrased. What I want to do is, is pass the response to the error handler, but i don't want to execute it, until we get to the Try:except clause in on_response method. So when we get the response and if it's not successful, then check the error code and raise the exception. Now what i'm doing is checking first for errors and then executing the check for success (error code)

Here is the **main**

```
def send_messages(self):
  response = cm.postData(url=simulateSasServer, jsondata=json_data)
  self.on_response(response)

def on_response(self, response):
myERRORS.myERRORS(response)
    # if registration is succesful change state to REGISTERED.
    if 'registrationResponse' in response:
        try:
            responseObjects = response['registrationResponse']
            for responseObject in responseObjects:
                if responseObject['error']['errorCode'] == 0:
                    do_action
        except myErrors.Version():
            raise ("version_message")
```

Here is the **myErrors**

```
class myERRORS(Exception):

error_code = {'SUCCESS': 0,
              'VERSION': 100,
              }

response_data = {}

def __init__(self, response):
    self.response_data.update(response)



class Version(myERRORS):

def __init__(self):
    self.name = "VERSION"
    self.err_code = self.error_code['VERSION']
    self.msg = "SAS protocol version used by CBSD is not supported by SAS"
    self.version_error()
    if self.version_error() is True:
        print (self.name, self.err_code, self.msg)
        raise Exception(self.name, self.err_code, self.msg)

def version_error(self):
    response_objects = self.response_data.values()[0]
    if 'registrationResponse' in self.response_data:
        for r_object in response_objects:
            if r_object['error']['errorCode'] == self.error_code['VERSION']:
                return True
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really anything special about exceptions.  They are classes.  What you did is create an instance of a class.  You did not raise it.  Change:

```
myERRORS.myERRORS(response)
```

to:

```
raise myERRORS.myERRORS(response)
```

Comment: Yeah, i guess my question was badly phrased. 

What I want to do is is pass the response to the error handler, but i don't want to execute it, until we get to the Try:except clause. 

So when we get the response and if it's not successful, then check the error code and raise the exception. 

Now what i'm doing is checking first for errors and then executing the check for success (error code)